# In jQuery, how do you resolve the scope of "this", when you are in the scope of each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I've created an Object, and have a method setup() in the object.

```
this.debug = function (){...}

this.setup = function(){    

  var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");

  fieldsets.each(function(){        
    this.debug($(this).attr("class")));
  });


}
```

I'm trying to call this.debug which is in the scope of the Object but not in the scope of each, since THIS is a different this...

How do I access this.debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say `var that = this` after this.debug, then do `that.debug`.

Comment: this and that... that.funny = 101

Comment: this should work.  Put that = this at the beginning of the setup() method.  (By work, I mean invoke the debug() method correctly, it could still throw an error.)

Comment: you really want do `var that = this`. Leaving out the var is a bad idea in general.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle - it's been a while since I last wrote any JavaScript :P You forget these little details...

Answer (score 3):

This is basically Skilldrik's answer, but showing you where it works best

```
this.setup = function(){    
  // save it in a scoped var...  some people use "self" for this purpose, i prefer
  // naming it whatever the outer object actually is...
  var containingObject = this;

  var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");

  fieldsets.each(function(){        
    // use that scoped var later!
    containingObject.debug($(this).attr("class")));
  });      
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, if your debug method doesn't use instance data, you can call it in a static context: ContainingObject.debug($(this).attr("class")));.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.4 you can do:

```
this.debug = function (){...}

this.setup = function(){    

  var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");

  fieldsets.each(jQuery.proxy(function(){
    this.debug($(this).attr("class")));
  },this);
}
```

The jQuery.proxy(function, object) function will take 2 arguments:

- The function will be the function used in the loop.
- The object argument will be the `this` object inside the function.

In this way, you can transfer the `this` from the outer scope inside the `each` function.

Comment: Very useful for converting a former for loop into a `jQuery.each` function; the `var that = this;` trick doesn't work as well if within the each anonymous function you define another anonymous function that depends on the outer `this`. The local variable `that` will be gone before the inner function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my Greasemonkey-Console:

```
this.debug = function() {
    console.log("foo");
};

this.setup = function() {

    var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");

    fieldsets.each(function(){
        debug($(this).attr("class"));
    });
};
```

Which will search the scope for any debug .. which that is hopefully the function above. This will fail, if you assign a variable with the very same name :)

Comment: `this` in the `foreach` loop will contain the fieldset object of the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do it this way: (note:example below is from memory but looks sound):

```
function CustomObject()
{
  var _instance = this;

  this.debug = function(){...};
  this.setup =
    function()
    {    
      var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");
      fieldsets.each(
        function()
        {        
          _instance.debug($(this).attr("class"));
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.debug = function (){...}

this.setup = function(){    
  var that = this;
  var fieldsets = form.children("fieldset");

  fieldsets.each(function(){        
    that.debug($(this).attr("class")));
  });


}
```